# Lubuntu - No session for pid xxxx

Tags: lubuntu

I'm on (L)Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I've installed Texlive 2107 and removed TL16. When I log in I receive the error: `No session for pid xxxx`.

Moreover I don't see the network icon on the bottom-right and I cannot connect to internet. I can't also see the shutdown button if I try to shutdown.

Edit: if I try to access the network I receive: `error accessing system permissions: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any service files`. I receive this problem in many other situations

Edit1: it's seems a problem of *Polkit agent*

Edit2:

When I log in I received  `No session for pid 1119`.

```
ps 1119
PID  TTY STAT TIME COMMAND
1119 ?   Ssl  0:00 /usr/bin/lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

If I go to 
"Preferences" -> "Default applications for LXsession" -> "Core applications" and press "Reload" for lxpolkit as the polkit agent, I get `No session for pid 1370`.

```
ps 1370
PID  TTY STAT TIME COMMAND
1370 ?   S  0:00   lxpolkit
```